# Reading new line giving syntax error in LEX YACC

Tags: parsing, yacc, lex

I am trying to parse a code, and for that i have written LEX and YACC file which will given below. first line it is reading correctly but after that it is giving syntax error, it is not reading next line,should i modify input and unput function,i am reading from file and writing my output in a file.....i have just started using LEX YACC, need some of the idea.

input file

```
b_7 = _6 + b_3;
a_8 = b_7 - c_5;
```

lex file

```
    %{
        /*
            parser for ssa;
        */

    #include<stdio.h>
    #include<stdlib.h>
    #include"y.tab.h"


    %}
    %%
    [\t]+   ;
    \n  ;



    [if]+       printf("first input\n");
    [else]+     return(op);
    [=]+        return(equal);
    [+]+        return(op);
    [*]+        return(op);
    [-]+        return(op);

    [\<][b][b][ ]+[1-9][\>] {return(bblock);}

    ([[_][a-z]])|([a-z][_][0-9]+)|([0-9]+)  {return(var);}

    .   ;




    %%
```

yacc file

```
%{
/* lexer for ssa gramer to use for recognizing operations*/
#include<stdio.h>
char add_graph(char,char,...);

%}

%token  opif opelse equal op bblock var

%%

sentence: var equal var op var  { add_graph($1,$2,$3,$4,$5);} 

    ;


%%
extern FILE *yyin;
main(argc,argv)
int argc;
char **argv;
{
    if(argc > 1) {
        FILE *file;
        file=fopen(argv[1],"r");
        if(file==NULL) {
            fprintf(stderr,"couldnot open%s\n",argv[0]);
            exit(1);
        }
        yyin=file;
    }
      do
    {
    yyparse();
    }while (!feof(yyin));
fclose(yyin);
}
char add_graph(something)
{
.....
.....
}

yyerror(s)
char *s;
{
    fprintf(stderr,"%s there is error\n",s);
}
yywrap()
{
printf("the output");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your grammar only permits one `sentence`.  So if there is any input after the first sentence, an error will be raised.  You want to permit one or more sentences.  Try this in your .y file:

```
%%
sentences : sentences sentence
          | sentence
          ;
sentence  : var equal var op var  { add_graph($1,$2,$3,$4,$5);}
          ;
%%
```

Comment: yes david, i have write your code and i have added one more line in lex file as chris told and it works                                             ";"            ;

Answer (score 1):

Lots of problems here:

- your grammar is expecting the token `op`, but your lexer will never produce it, instead producing `opadd` `opmul` etc
- your example has `;` at the end of lines, but neither your lexer nor parser deal with them.  The default lexer action of copying to stdout is almost never what you want.
- your yacc file tries to use `\\` as some sort of comment marker, but yacc doesn't understand that.  Some versions of yacc understand C++-style `//` as a comment, but not all
- your grammar only allows for one sentence in the input
- your sentence has a spurious `op` at the end (on the next line), which is not a separate sentence rule -- you need `|` to separate rules.
- you attempt to loop if you haven't reached the eof when `yyparse` returns, but if there's an error, its likely that the input will still have some cruft that will cause an immediate error, resulting in an error storm -- probably not what you want.

Answer (score -1):

DAVID IS SAYING CORRECT BUT ONE MORE MODIFICATION NEED TO BE MADE

ADD

```
";"     ;
```

SEE IF THIS CAN HELP.acknowledge me if i am wrong.