# How to tokenize String in Lex and Yacc

Tags: c, yacc, lex

with reference to [Reading new line giving syntax error in LEX YACC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22346554/reading-new-line-giving-syntax-error-in-lex-yacc)
 lex file we are using

```
 %{
        /*
            parser for ssa;
        */

    #include<stdio.h>
    #include<stdlib.h>
    #include"y.tab.h"


    %}
    %%
    [\t]+   ;
    \n  ;



    [if]+       printf("first input\n");
    [else]+     return(op);
    [=]+        return(equal);
    [+]+        return(op);
    [*]+        return(op);
    [-]+        return(op);

    [\<][b][b][ ]+[1-9][\>] {return(bblock);}

    ([[_][a-z]])|([a-z][_][0-9]+)|([0-9]+)  {return(var);}

    .   ;




    %%
```

what should i do if i want to get token as a string i.e a_2
how to do it????

input file is

```
a_2 = _6 + b_3; 
  a_8 = b_7 - c_5;
```

---

Comment: You know that `[if]+` will match any non-empty string containing only the letters `f` and `i`, right? So it will match f, fififi, iffif, and a lot of other things which don't seem like what you're looking for. To be honest, I don't understand your usage the regex `+` operator at all. Why would you want "any number of `=`" to be a single token?

Comment: yes,i know code needs to be modified......i posted code to get info about string token.....ill modify it....thanks dear :)

Answer (score 1):

You can define token type in your bison file:

```
%union{
 char *string;
}

%token <string> var
```

and then replace

```
return(var);
```

with

```
yylval.string=malloc(yyleng); sprintf(yylval.string,"%s",yytext);return var;
```

Comment: The malloc() is one too short. The whole thing can be replaced by yylval.string = strdup(yytext);

Comment: thanks ziollek, EJP. if i want  VAR as parameter in a function in my yacc file, how can i do that, i have used $$,$1 but it is giving error.....cant i take VAR as a parameter in my function?

Comment: Sorry, but who is responsible for freeing that string after parsing is done?